# Storing ERB Expression in a Ruby String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm building a webpage in an html.erb file. It includes 20 cards with the same elements, each of which includes a link. I would like to build the card once, iterating through a Ruby hash to build the rest.

However, some of the card paragraphs include an ERB expression, and I haven't been able to find a way to include it within the hash. Is there a workaround to storing this information within a hash?

Here's an example of how I'm trying to store the information, with the "paragraph" value being the issue:

```
{
  "product1" => {
    "title" => "The Best Product for Your Needs",
    "paragraph" => "Find out more <%= link_to 'here', 'https://www.product.com' %> about what this product can do for you."
  }
}
```

I have tried regex escape `\`, different combinations of quotes (`'` vs `"`), and Ruby string interpolation (`#{<%= ... %>}`).

Thanks!

Comment: I must be missing something. I don’t see what the problem is. Can you be more specific?  It looks to me like it should work exactly as you have it written.

Comment: If you want to evaluate that ERB expr inside paragraph you may need to [render before you print inside your component](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/ERB.html) and than print into your component using `<%= raw ERB.new(item["paragraph"]).result(binding) %>`

Comment: @MichaelB, it throws an error on ERB within the string and the page 404's.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is render the "paragraph" text as ERB code.

While you can do this with something like...

```
<%= raw ERB.new(@hash[:product1][:paragraph]).render(binding) %>
```

It's an odd thing to do and I wouldn't recommend mixing in view logic into the data passed into your view.

A more common approach is to pass in the information that the view needs to render and that's it. For example, pass in the URL you want linked and render it like this:

```
# in a controller...
@product_hashes = {
  "product1" => {
     "title" => "The Best Product for Your Needs",
     "url" => "https://www.product.com"
  }
}  
# in the view
<% product_hashes.each do |product_key, product_hash| %>
  <div class='title'><%= product_hash['title'] ></div>
  <div class='description'> Find out more <%= link_to 'here', product['url'] %> about what this product can do for you.</div>
<% end %>
```

I'd also wonder why we're passing in a hash at all. More common is to use the objects from your database directly in the view. Something like...

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class='title'><%= product.title ></div>
  <div class='description'> Find out more <%= link_to 'here', product.url %> about what this product can do for you.</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! The objects aren't stored in the database, which is why I'm going with the former option. The issue is that I need to store the url within in a sentence, and that sentence and link will be different on each card. I tried your suggestions, but I couldn't get them to work with url embedded in the sentence.

Comment: Can you post the error message? But yeah, generally speaking i'd probably recommend taking a different approach. Even just using raw HTML instead of using ERB interpolation, or creating a template file for each product and passing in an array of view partials to render instead.

Comment: Actually - another option is to have the text fields written in markdown syntax and use a gem to parse to html (to make the links into links). https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown `Kramdown::Document.new(text).to_html`